# Attempting to copy and paste with VBA using a range created by a cell's value

Tags: vba, excel

Every time I try to step through this, I get a syntax error and I don't know why. I'm trying to create a variable so I can select a range of cells based on the value in the cell "M1" on the 'transform' sheet.

```
Sheets("transform").Select
Dim variableRange As Integer
    variableRange = ActiveSheet.Range.("M1").Value
```

This seems like really basic stuff - I'm still attempting to learn about VBA, I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: What is the value in M1?

Comment: Should that be `ActiveSheet.Range("M1").Value`?  You have an extra `.` between `Range` and `()`.

Comment: `variableRange = Worksheets("transform").Range("M1").Value` works even nicer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an extra period in there. Should be:

```
variableRange = ActiveSheet.Range("M1").Value
```